# useEffect not triggered on react hook form change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-hook-form

looking to use react hook form with useEffect to get changes in real time (as the user is filling out the form), is there a reason why useEffect isn't triggered here and if so is there a way to trigger it whenever the form data changes? example here is from https://remotestack.io/react-hook-form-set-update-form-values-with-useeffect-hook/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function SimpleForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState } = useForm();

  const [student, initStudent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        initStudent({
          name: "Little Johnny",
          email: "lil@johnny.com",
          grade: "3rd",
        }),
      1200
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updating.,..");

    reset(student);
  }, [reset, student]);

  function onFormSubmit(dataRes) {
    console.log(dataRes);
    return false;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="mb-3">
        React Initiate Form Values in useEffect Hook Example
      </h2>

      {student && (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              {...register("name")}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              {...register("email")}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Grade</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="grade"
              {...register("grade")}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark">
            Send
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
      {!student && (
        <div className="text-center p-3">
          <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-center"></span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to  set state using ```initStudent``` on every onChange then only your useEffect will triggger

Comment: You've 2 `useEffect` hooks, which are you referring to specifically? One runs only once when the component mounts since it has an empty dependency array, and the other looks like it also runs twice, once when the component mounts and once again from the enqueued update, and then never again because nothing updates any of its dependencies. What exactly is the issue here? What are you expecting to happen? What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: @DrewReese I want 2nd use effect to somehow be triggered, goal is to console log "updating..." because the form is being updated as the user is filling out the form, but this is not happening

Comment: Right, you are updating form state. So you just want to trigger a console log stating the inputs are being interacted with, or indirectly that the form state is being updated?

Comment: @DrewReese yes exactly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `watch` mode of react hook form to get every change.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState, watch } = useForm();


useEffect(() => {
    watch((value, { name, type }) => console.log(value, name, type));
 }, [watch]);
```

Read more about watch mode form [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch)

Comment: What if you don't want to listen for every change though and only a subset of the form?

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Answer (score -1):

You need to trigger a state change whenever your input field value changes, and you do so using `onClick` event attribute like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function SimpleForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState } = useForm();

  const [student, initStudent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        initStudent({
          name: "Little Johnny",
          email: "lil@johnny.com",
          grade: "3rd",
        }),
      1200
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updating.,..");

    reset(student);
  }, [reset, student]);

  function onFormSubmit(dataRes) {
    console.log(dataRes);
    return false;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="mb-3">
        React Initiate Form Values in useEffect Hook Example
      </h2>

      {student && (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              {...register("name")}
              onClick={(e)=>initStudent({...student, name: e.target.value})}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              {...register("email")}
              onClick={(e)=>initStudent({...student, email: e.target.value})}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Grade</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="grade"
              {...register("grade")}
              onClick={(e)=>initStudent({...student, grade: e.target.value})}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark">
            Send
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
      {!student && (
        <div className="text-center p-3">
          <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-center"></span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: While *technically* true it's a general React anti-pattern to duplicate state. I think we need to first understand what the OP is really trying to accomplish and fix that and not propagate bad coding patterns.